# Error: suite.go:61: test panicked: reflect: Call with too few input arguments

Tags: unit-testing, go, testify

I'm setting unit test in `golang`.
But now I'm facing error when running `go test -v`.
 
I want to resolve this error and make test success.

```
article
  ├ client
  ├ api
  │  ├ main.go
  │  ├ contoroller
  │  │    ├ contoroller.go
  │  │    └ contoroller_test.go
  │  ├ service
  │  │    ├ service.go
  │  │    └ service_test.go
  │  ├ dao
  │  │    ├ dao.go
  │  │    └ dao_test.go
  │  ├ s3
  │  │    ├ s3.go
  │  │    └ s3_test.go
  │  ├ go.mod 
  │  ├ go.sum
  │  └ Dockerfile
  ├ nginx
  └ docker-compose.yml
```

Now I'm setting `service_test.go` for `service.go`.

service_test.go

```golang
package service

// import

type MockDaoInterface struct {
}

func (_m *MockDaoInterface) GetArticleDao() *sql.Rows {
    db, mock, _ := sqlmock.New()
    mockRows := mock.NewRows([]string{"id", "uuid", "title", "content"}).
        AddRow(1, "bea1b24d-0627-4ea0-aa2b-8af4c6c2a41c", "test", "test").
        AddRow(2, "844bc620-7336-41a3-9cb4-552a0024ff1c", "test2", "test2")
    mock.ExpectQuery("select").WillReturnRows(mockRows)
    rows, _ := db.Query("select")
    return rows
}


type ServiceSuite struct {
    suite.Suite
    service *Service
    dao     dao.DaoInterface
}

func (s *ServiceSuite) SetupTest() {
    s.service = NewService(s.dao)
    s.service.dao = &MockDaoInterface{}
}

func (s *ServiceSuite) TestGetArticleService(t *testing.T) {

    articles := s.service.GetArticleService()

    var expectedArticles []util.Article

    expectedArticle1 := util.Article{
        ID:      1,
        UUID:    "bea1b24d-0627-4ea0-aa2b-8af4c6c2a41c",
        TITLE:   "test",
        CONTENT: "test",
    }
    expectedArticles = append(expectedArticles, expectedArticle1)

    expectedArticle2 := util.Article{
        ID:      2,
        UUID:    "844bc620-7336-41a3-9cb4-552a0024ff1c",
        TITLE:   "test2",
        CONTENT: "test2",
    }
    expectedArticles = append(expectedArticles, expectedArticle2)

    assert.Equal(s.T(), expectedArticles, articles)
}

func TestServiceSuite(t *testing.T) {
    suite.Run(t, new(ServiceSuite))
}
```

service.go

```golang
package service

// import 

type Service struct {
    dao dao.DaoInterface
}

func NewService(dao dao.DaoInterface) *Service {
    return &Service{dao: dao}
}

func (s Service) GetArticleService() []util.Article {
    var articles []util.Article

    results := s.dao.GetArticleDao()

    article := util.Article{}
    for results.Next() {
        err := results.Scan(&article.ID, &article.UUID, &article.TITLE, &article.CONTENT)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        } else {
            articles = append(articles, article)
        }
    }
    return articles
}
```

dao.go

```golang
package dao

// import

type Dao struct {
    database *sql.DB
    s3       s3.S3Interface
}

func NewDao(database *sql.DB, s3 s3.S3Interface) *Dao {
    objs := &Dao{database: database, s3: s3}
    return objs
}

type DaoInterface interface {
    GetArticleDao() *sql.Rows
}
```

Here is the full source code(branch: go-test-service)
https://github.com/jpskgc/article/tree/go-test-service

I expect `service_test.go` to success test.
But the actual is it fails with error.
I want to resolve this error and to success test.

```
$ go test -v
=== RUN   TestServiceSuite
=== RUN   TestServiceSuite/TestGetArticleService
--- FAIL: TestServiceSuite (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestServiceSuite/TestGetArticleService (0.00s)
        suite.go:61: test panicked: reflect: Call with too few input arguments
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    article/api/service     0.045s
```

Comment: Before you fix this error, you need to seriously start closing the returned `*sql.Rows` object. Please see `database/sql` documentation on how to properly use that type of result. If you don't do it, your program will keep crashing because of too-many-connections open.

Answer (score 54):

It's resolved by removing `t *testing.T` from aurgument.

```
func (s *ServiceSuite) TestGetArticleService() {
// some code
}
```

Comment: @TehSphinX, its correct to remove `t *testing.T` from argument. The user is using package "suite" in which, we do not need to send the "`t *testing.T`" parameter as`go test` doesn't run this test function `TestGetArticleService` directly, but "`suite`" will. To get the testing context, one needs to use suite.T() within the function.

Comment: you must use T() from suite

Comment: @VanagaS is correct in that you need to use `suite.T()`, thanks!

Comment: Hm, but I still have this error...

Answer (score 4):

This method should not have any parameter

```
func (s *ServiceSuite) TestGetArticleService(t *testing.T) {
```

change it to

```
func (s *ServiceSuite) TestGetArticleService() {
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

```
type AnswerApplicationSvcTestSuite struct {
    mock.Mock
    suite.Suite
    svc                   *answerApplicationService
}
```

My problem is hesitating to nest both mock.Mock and suete.Suite

I tried to delete mock.Mock

Then it's back to normal

Answer (score 0):

My solution was

`go generate ./...`

because of mocks expected inputs.